# MySQL subquery issue

Tags: mysql

The result i want,'

```
price1   |  price2 
1. 10000 |  2. -100 
3. 20000 |  4. -200
```

the queries that will be selected,

1. `select total_price from cloud_payment where user_id='snoopy99' and demandnum= '201307-charge0000040C'`
2. `select unpaid_price from gcloud.cloud_service_basic where user_id='snoopy99' and month=7`
3. `select total_price from gcloud.cloud_payment where user_id='snoopy99' and demandnum= '201308-charge0000040C'`
4. `select unpaid_price from gcloud.cloud_service_basic where user_id='snoopy99' and month=8`

I want **1,3** to be in the first column
**2,4** to be in the second column.

Any good idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try.

```
select total_price as price from cloud_payment where user_id='snoopy99' and (demandnum= '201307-charge0000040C' OR demandnum= '201308-charge0000040C')
UNION ALL
select unpaid_price as price from gcloud.cloud_service_basic where user_id='snoopy99' and ( month=7 OR month=8)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JOIN` to select a merged record from your service and payment tables, then `UNION` to select two such records. Something like this:

```
SELECT total_price, unpaid_price
    FROM  cloud_payment cp
    JOIN  gcloud.cloud_service_basic cs ON cp.user_id = cs.user_id
    WHERE cp.user_id = 'snoopy99'
    AND   cp.demandnum = '201307-charge0000040C'
    AND   cs.month = 7
UNION
SELECT total_price, unpaid_price
    FROM  cloud_payment cp2
    JOIN  gcloud.cloud_service_basic cs2 ON cp2.user_id = cs2.user_id
    WHERE cp2.user_id = 'snoopy99'
    AND   cp2.demandnum = '201308-charge0000040C'
    AND   cs2.month = 8
;
```

[Example SQLFiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0dd07/3)